# Prevent "MATLAB" folder in My Documents

Tags: matlab

I have Matlab (2009b, Windows 7) set up to start in a special folder where I keep all my Matlab files and a startup script. This folder is not in "My Documents"

Still, Matlab creates an empty folder called "MATLAB" in "My Documents" every time it is started. This is very annoying since this change propagates to other computers which share the document folder. How can I prevent this?

Comment: oh, yes ... i hate that too (in general, all apps that create folders wherever they wish)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`userpath('clear')`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/userpath.html) should do the trick.

[edit]: As per comments, on some (newer?) systems, you may have to set `userpath` to an existing folder, i.e. `userpath('<new_path>')`

Comment: This did not work for me in MATLAB 2018b. I had to do `userpath('<new_path>')`

Comment: Also didn't work for me with MATLAB 2021a on macOS. Specifying an actual path (as @binaryfunt proposed) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a new location for this folder:

```
>> userpath \Location\of\your\choice
```

You can you for instance a hidden folder. In my case I used `~/Documents/.matlab` on my Linux laptop.